# Need Something That Catagorizes Word Based On Vocab Level

Tags: java, string, vocabulary, plagiarism-detection

I'm doing a plagiarism type project in Java and would like to somehow give each word a rating based on how strong the word choice is. Is there anything that does this or any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also look at projects like [Flesh [a Flesch-Kincaid readability index engine].](http://flesh.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). Its [MoreLikeThis](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/mlt/MoreLikeThis.html) feature is probably the best suited to solve this problem.